# Subset of Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A\subset C$ and $B\subset D$ if and only if $A \times B\subset C \times D$.

Prove if is correct or incorrect.

How to start this, I don't know?
is this true or not true?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE Here is a mathjax guide to render mathematics properly http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @epsilondelta why did you change subset to proper subset?

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream Usually we use this for subset. For proper subset we use this with a cutting line under it. I will change it if this notation is confusing.

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream just for my records (because in my case it's because I don't know how to in LaTeX) is that a big deal, I tend to use $\subset$ with a line under when writing to make it more distinct, and $\subset$ here. I also have problems writing $\cup$ compared to $U$

Comment: @AlecTeal In latex you may type "\subseteq"

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $A \subseteq C$, so $a \in C$ for all $a \in A$,
and $B \subseteq D$, so $b \in D$ for all $b \in B$.

Then $A \times B = \{ (a, b) \mid a \in A, b \in B \} \subseteq
\{ (a,b) \mid a \in C, b \in D \} = C \times D$.

On the other hand, suppose $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$.
Then, for any $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, $(a, b) \in C \times D$.
Therefore, $a \in C$ and $b \in D$.
So $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$.

Comment: i do not understand if it is true or not. @rafalpw gave a counterexample but i am not sure

Comment: It is true. raflpw did not give a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A=D=\emptyset $ and $B=C=\lbrace a \rbrace $ for some $a$.

Comment: then B can not be subset of D because {a} is not an element of null set?

Comment: @rafalpw: Here $B$ is not a subset of $D$.